# How to dynamically change a CSS property of a component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a few images on my page and I want to change their opacity with JS using timeout. For example, first image has opacity 1 for 5 seconds, then I change it's opacity to 0 and set opacity 1 to the second image. Here's my code for the images

```
<Box component="img" src={imageSrc} alt="slide" key={imageSrc}
          className="image"
          sx={{
            opacity: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            objectFit: 'cover',
            transition: 'opacity 2s',
          }}
        />)}
```

But I'm new to Material UI and have no idea how to implement this. Can't use CSS modules btw :(

Answer (score 0):

Make opacity a state: `const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0)`
Then in your timeout function, update the state. And use that state in your styles.

Comment: Yes and in the sx attribute of one image  you add opacity : opacity ? 1 : 0  and for the other one use opacity : !opacity ? 1 : 0 that way you make sure that if one is visible the other isn't

Comment: @AlaaEddineCherif how whould I set opacity 1 for one and opacity 0 to other images when they all are rendered with map?

Comment: If i'm understanding this right you want to implement a slideshow right ?  If so instead of your state being a int you can make it into an array of a lot of zeros and a 1 . the one indicating which image is visible each image should get opacity: opacity[key] and your state update removes the 1 that's set and sets it for the next image using findIndex (you find the index you make it 0 and if its the end of array do array[0]=1 else array[i+1]=1